# Gnu parallel and multiple nodes using rsh instead ssh

Tags: gnu-parallel

Can I use rsh instead of ssh to split jobs between nodes in an hpc setup?

Or gnu-parallel only can send different jobs by ssh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `--ssh` to set the ssh command:

```
parallel --ssh rsh ...
```

Or `$PARALLEL_SSH`:

```
PARALLEL_SSH=rsh
export PARALLEL_SSH
parallel ...
```

Or do it on a server-by-server basis:

```
parallel -S '/usr/bin/rsh my_rsh_server' -S my_ssh_server ...
```

Comment: as I can jump to my allocated nodes seamlessly with rsh this is an acceptable answer. thank you:)